# 'Can't use an undefined value as filehandle reference' error in Perl

Tags: perl

I am getting this error when I run my perl script:

> Can't use an undefined value as filehandle reference at scr line 44.

Line 44:

```
open my $fh, "|-", "mail", "-s", $subject, $owner, "-c", $sendto
    or die "$0: could not start mail: $!";
```

Everything looks okay. What does the error mean?

Comment: Do you have an ancient version of perl, such as 5.005 or so, installed?

Comment: Why are you working with a nine year old version of Perl? Update your Perl, your sysadmin or your job :-)

Comment: http://blog.urth.org/2010/11/what-versions-of-core-perl-should-module-authors-support.html

Answer (score 4):

I think the error message is in error. This code:

```
open my $fh, '|-', 'perl', '-v' or die "$!\n";
```

dies with the error message

> Can't use an undefined value as filehandle reference...

under Perl 5.6.1, but dies with

> List form of pipe open not implemented...

under Perl 5.12.1 (on Win32).

"List form" means specifying the program and its arguments as separate values. The single-value form runs on both versions:

```
open my $fh, '|-', 'perl -v' or die "$!\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty old perl, I'm guessing that that version doesn't support lexical file handles so "open my $fh" won't work as ancient perl will see that as, essentially, `open undef` and hence the error message. Possible solutions:

- Upgrade your perl out of the bronze age.
- Use the old school `open FH` syntax instead.
- Use `gensym` to generate a symbol that you can use as a file handle.
- Use one of the `IO::*` classes of plain `open`.

Comment: It supports lexical filehandles: `my $fh = "STDIN"` is of course a lexical filehandle; so is `my $fh = do{local *FH}`.  It simply doesn’t support the autovivification of lvaluable arguments previously undefined into references to typeglobs blessed into the `IO::Handle` package with a destructor to close and hide any failure on said handle — which is a different thing.

Comment: So I'm thinking around the right area then: upgrade perl or downgrade the code. Been awhile since I've dealt with 5.6 and I switched to `IO::Handle` as soon I found out about it.